# Geolocation not working with PhoneGap Build in Android

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, geolocation, phonegap-build

Geolocation not working with PhoneGap Build in Android

I add in config.xml :

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
```

And

```
<preference name="permissions" value="INTERNET" />
```

The complete config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "org.test.geo"
        versionCode="10"
        version   = "1.0">
        <name>Geo Test.</name>
        <description>Geo Test.</description>
        <author email="prueba@prueba.com">
            Geo
        </author>


    <!-- PREFERENCE -->     
        <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
        <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
        <preference name="permissions" value="INTERNET" />

    <!-- PLATFORM -->
        <gap:platform name="android" />     

    <!-- FEATURE -->        
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    </widget>
```

I use the example code from: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html

In index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                            'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                            'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                            'Timestamp: '          + position.timestamp                    + '<br />';
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I try in Virtual devices and physical devices. I can only get "Finding geolocation..."

No error. But the problem seems to be in  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

Thanks!

Comment: Now this will sound very very weird but try this. Install the app, restart  the device once. and open the app. see what happens.

Comment: Can you please include your config.xml file in your question?

Comment: I add my config.xml in the first message now.